# Angular2 - fetch json value to replace value into html template

Tags: html, angular, typescript

New to angular2, having problems infetching the value from the Footer[] array and display it.

### **footer.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Footer {
  id: number;
  value: string;
}

const FOOTER : Footer[] = [
    {id: 1, value: 'value_one'},
    {id: 2, value: 'value_two'}
  ];

@Component({
    selector: 'footer',
    template: `<html-outlet [html]="footerValue"></html-outlet>`,
})
export class FooterComponent{
    foot = FOOTER;

    footerValue = `<div class="menu" *ngFor="let f of foot" >
                <div class="footer"><b>{{f.value}} @2016</b></div>
            </div>`;
}
```

The sinnept:

```
template:`<html-outlet [html]="footerValue"></html-outlet>`,
```

takes the template from 'footerValue' and sends to another function for compiling and loading the html dynamically.

All works well if its passed directly as:

```
template: `<div class="menu" *ngFor="let f of foot" >
                <div class="footer"><b>{{f.value}} @2016</b></div>
            </div>`,
```

Can someone guide me how to append the values from the array to the string variable 'footerValue', to follow my original functionality to generate the html dinamically.

Original html template is :

```
`<div class="menu" *ngFor="let f of foot" >
                <div class="footer"><b>Example @2016</b></div>
            </div>`
```

where the 'Example' should get replaced with value from the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is that your `html-outlet` tries to "compile" your html-snippet but don't know what `foot` is..

So prepare your html-snippet like this:

```js
constructor() {
   this.footerValue = this.prepareFooterHtml();
}

prepareFooterHtml(): string {
   let footer = '<div class="menu">';
   this.foot.forEach(f => {
      footer += `<div class="footer"><b>${f.value} @2016</b></div>`;
   });
   footer += '</div>';
   return footer;
}
```

Comment: will give it a try and see

Comment: @mxii..its taking only the second value from the array..how about if I need the first value..where do I place that condition?

Comment: `this.foot.forEach()` will iterate over the whole array! you can put `console.log(f)` to it and see what array-entries are processed.